# Transformation order reversed in glMatrix?

Tags: transformation, gl-matrix

[image]

In both scenes the transformations have to be swapped in glMatrix.

i.e. to achieve 1) in glMatrix:

```
mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, [0.6, 0.0, 0.0]);
mat4.rotateZ(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, degToRad(45));
```

Why is the transformation order reversed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not only the case for WebGL, but for OpenGL in general. And indeed, it may be confusing: The order in which the transformations are *applied* is the opposite of the order in which they appear in the source code.

A simplified/shortened "pseudocode" version of the code that you provided is the following:

```
M = identity();
M = M * T; // Where T = Translation
M = M * R; // Where R = Rotation
```

An even shorter form of writing this would be

```
M = T * R;
```

Now imagine that you transform a vertex with this matrix - this can be written as

```
transformedVertex = M * vertex
```

Recalling that `M = T * R`, this is the same as

```
transformedVertex = T * R * vertex
```

You could also write it as

```
transformedVertex = T * (R * vertex)
```

or, to make it even more obvious:

```
rotatedVertex = R * vertex
transformedVertex = T * rotatedVertex
```

So the vertex is rotated first. (And then, the rotated vertex is translated)

---

Of course, you basically *can* turn things around. The usual way of multiplying matrices in OpenGL is the "post-multiplication" or "right-multiplication", in the form

```
newMatrix = oldMatrix * additionalTransformation
```

(like you have done it in your code). The alternative would be to write

```
newMatrix = additionalTransformation * oldMatrix
```

This is sometimes called "pre-multiplication" or "left-multiplication". So you could also write

```
M = identity();
M = T * M; // Where T = Translation
M = R * M; // Where R = Rotation
```

so that in the end,

```
M = R * T
```

In this case, the translation appears before the rotation in the source code, and the translation would also be applied *before* the rotation.

But in the context of OpenGL, this is rather unusual. (And *mixing* both ways would be very confusing - I would not recommend this).

---

A side note: All this may have made a bit more sense at the time when [`glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name6) have still been part of the OpenGL API. The way of thinking about this resembles the traversal of a scene graph. You first apply the "global" transformations, and then the "local" ones.

---

### Update:

<sub>In response to the comments: I'll try to write a few words that may justify certain concepts. Summarizing this here is a bit difficult. I'll try to simplify it, and omit some details that likely are beyond the scope of a single answer here. Some of these things mentioned here refer to how things have been done in earlier versions of OpenGL and are solved differently nowadays - although many of the *concepts* are still the same!</sub>

It is not uncommon to represent 3D scenes in form of a *scene graph*. This is a hierarchically structured representation of the scene, ususally in form of a tree:

```
             root
            /    \
       nodeA      nodeB
      /  \           \
nodeA0    nodeA1    nodeB0
object    object    object
```

The nodes contain transformation matrices (e.g. rotation or translation). The 3D objects are attached to these nodes. During rendering, this graph is traversed: Each node is visited, and its object will be rendered. This is done recursively, starting at the root, and visiting all children, down to the leaves. For example, the renderer may visit the above nodes in the following order:

```
root 
  nodeA
    nodeA0
    nodeA1
  nodeB
    nodeB0
```

During this traversal, the renderer maintains a "matrix stack". In earlier OpenGL versions, there have been dedicated methods for maintaining this stack. For example, [`glPushMatrix`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) to push a copy of the current "top" matrix on the stack, and `glPopMatrix` to remove the topmost matrix from the stack. Or [`glMultMatrix`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml) to multiply the current "top" matrix of the stack with another one.

When an object was rendered, it was always rendered with the matrix that was on the top of this stack. (There have been no shaders and `mat4` uniforms back then...)

So the renderer could render the scene graph with a simple recursive method like this (pseudocode) :

```
void render(Node node) {

    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrix(node.matrix);

    renderObject(node.object);

    foreach (child in node.children) {
        render(child);
    }

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

By "enclosing" the rendering into a `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix` pair, the renderer could always maintain the right current matrix for the node that it was visiting. Now, the renderer visited these nodes, and maintained the matrix stack:

```
Node:           Matrix Stack:
-----------------------------
root            identity 
  nodeA         identity * nodeA.matrix 
    nodeA0      identity * nodeA.matrix * nodeA0.matrix
    nodeA1      identity * nodeA.matrix * nodeA1.matrix
  nodeB         identity * nodeB.matrix
    nodeB0      identity * nodeB.matrix * nodeB0.matrix
```

One can see that the matrix that is used for rendering an object in a node is given by the product of all matrices along the path from the root to the respective node.

The possible performance benefits and elegance of these concepts may become more obvious when considering a "large" scene graph:

```
root
  nodeA
    nodeB
      nodeC
        nodeD0
        nodeD1
        nodeD2
        ...
        nodeD1000
```

One could compute the product

```
nodeA.matrix * nodeB.matrix * nodeC.matrix
```

**once**, and then multiply the matrices of the `nodeD0` ... `nodeD1000` always with this matrix. Conversely, **if** one wanted to turn the multiplication around, one would have to compute

```
nodeD0.matrix * nodeC.matrix * nodeB.matrix * nodeA.matrix
nodeD1.matrix * nodeC.matrix * nodeB.matrix * nodeA.matrix
...
nodeD1000.matrix * nodeC.matrix * nodeB.matrix * nodeA.matrix
```

wasting lots of resources for matrix multiplications. (These redundant computations could then have been avoided with other methods, but these would not nearly have been so elegant and easy).

Comment: I'd be curious to hear why someone clicked on "This answer is not useful". Is anything missing or unclear?

Comment: @Maro13 In fact, it is detailed and comprehensive. One thing I didn't understand though is: Why does OpenGL have that transformation order? It would save us so much pain by just swapping the multiplication order in the transform operations.

Comment: @piegames When you write `T * R * vector`, then the "mathematical definition" (regardless of OpenGL) **is**, intuitively, that the vertex is first rotated and then translated. As already mentioned: You *can* write the code a bit differently to turn this around, but even if you write `M = Identity; M = T * M; M = R * T;`, then the result *will* be `M = R * T`, which still is "translate and then rotate". (Sorry, I'm not sure how to describe this in a way that sounds convincing. I tried to paint an image for the scene graph traversal, but this looked confusing...)

Comment: I (think I) understand the principles why the order is reversed and how it works. But in the doc: www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml it says "Calling glMultMatrix with an argument of m = [...] replaces the current transformation with C × M × v  [...]". at this point the order is arbitrary, the could have chosen M x C x v as well. But why that way? When I write transformations, i'ts intuitive to call transform operations in the order I want to have them applied. Even if this breaks with the mathematical way to use transforms, nobody programs in a mathematical notation.

Comment: @piegames From a certain perspective, mathematics and programming are **very** closely related. Arithmetic with `+-*/` operators, propositional calculus for `if`-statements, algebras for OOP..., and this may especially true for *computer graphics*, which is always related to matrices, vector spaces and the like. However, I added an **Update** to the answer, and hope that it is not tooo confusing.

Comment: Thank you. It really helps to think of the matrix stack as a scene graph (which I didn't previously because my scenes were always to small for a scene graph)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure this glMatrix is backward.

For example [watching these videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkY2DOUCWMU&index=5&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) it seems like it's standard to do

```
m1 * m2 * m3 * vector
```

and given the order shown in the video that would correspond to

```
gl_Position = projection * view * world * position;
```

which exactly matches GL and GLSL.

It also matches glMatrix.

```
var m = mat4.create();
mat4.projection(m, fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
mat4.multiply(m, m, view);
mat4.translate(m, m, [x, y, z]);
mat4.rotateY(m, m, someAngle);
mat4.scale(m, m, [sx, sy, sz]);
```

Exactly corresponds to

```
m = projection * 
    view * 
    translation * 
    rotation *
    scale;
```

Seems forward to me.

```js
var vs = `
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = texcoord;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
}
`;
var fs = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_diffuse, v_texCoord);
}
`;

"use strict";
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

var arrays = {
  position: [1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
  normal:   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1],
  texcoord: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  indices:  [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23],
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

var tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  min: gl.NEAREST,
  mag: gl.NEAREST,
  src: [
    255, 0, 0, 255,
    192, 192, 192, 255,
    0, 0, 192, 255,
    255, 0, 255, 255,
  ],
    });

    var uniforms = {
    u_lightWorldPos: [1, 8, -10],
  u_lightColor: [1, 0.8, 0.8, 1],
  u_ambient: [0, 0, 0, 1],
  u_specular: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  u_shininess: 50,
  u_specularFactor: 1,
  u_diffuse: tex,
};

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  var eye = [1, 4, -6];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];

  var view = mat4.create();
  var camera = mat4.create();
  
  // glMatrix's lookAt is arguably backward.
  // It's making an inverse lookAt which is far less useful.
  // There's one camera in the scene but hundreds of other
  // objects that might want to use a lookAt to you know, look at things.
  mat4.lookAt(view, eye, target, up);
  //mat4.lookAt(camera, eye, target, up);
  //mat4.invert(view, camera);
    
  var m = mat4.create();

  var fov = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var zNear = 0.5;
  var zFar = 10;
  mat4.perspective(m, fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  mat4.multiply(m, m, view);
  mat4.translate(m, m, [1, 0, 0]);
  mat4.rotateY(m, m, time);
  mat4.scale(m, m, [1, 0.5, 0.7]);
  
  uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m;
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, the series is really great!

Answer (score 0):

I now what you need , take a look at :

http://nidza.html-5.me/zlatnaspirala2/project/index.html

Source code :

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/zlatnaspirala2
https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/zlatnaspirala2/blob/master/project/zlatnaspirala/zlatnaspirala.js

Magic is :

```
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
        xRot = YY;
        yRot = alfa + XX;
        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(xRot), [1, 0, 0]);
        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix,  degToRad(yRot), [0, 1, 0]);
        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [transX +TX,transY + TY,transZ +TZ]);
```

1)Translate to zero

2)Rotate

3)Translate to last or current position in 3d world.